# Where can I find the error estimates for using quadratures in FEM for parabolic equations?

Tags: finite-element-method

guys.
I want to know where I can find something about variational crimes for using numerical integration in calculating integrals needed in FEM in case of a parabolic equation like Heat equation. All the articles and books about this matter are either too old to be found or about elliptical equations. Be noted that I need this for linear parabolic equations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically you choose quadrature rules in such a way that the integration is exact. Can you be more specific?